# OperationalError at /admin/app/orderitem/ no such column: app_orderitem.rent

Tags: django, django-models

I just newly created this django project in which i added mulitple models & one of them is orderItem. this has a rent option. but from /admin i can't enter the orderItem option nor i can create any orderItem. there's was no data before i started my project. why is it showing me ***OperationalError at /admin/app/orderitem/ no such column: app_orderitem.rent*** error?

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    rent = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False)
    date_ordered = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    date_rented = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_returned = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product) + " Order: (" + str(self.order)+")"
```

serializer.py

```
class orderItemSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def getOrderItemData(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        item = OrderItem.objects.all()
        serializer = orderItemSerializers(item, many=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.data)
        serializer = orderItemSerializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: likely you did not migrate your database (correctly).

Comment: yes i migrated the database. what do you mean by correctly btw?